# Jekyll creating navigation for blog pages

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid, jekyll-paginator

I am using jekyll-pagination on a site I am working on. I have a loop for a navbar, that loops through the sites pages, and adds them to the navbar. The navbar is picking up the extra paginated pages from the blog, and adding the "Blog" to the navbar over and over again.  Is there anyway to **only have "Blog" show up once**, and the additional blog pages be linked only in the blog?

Here is a grab of the navbar:

[image]

Here is the code for the navbar:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    {% assign mypages = site.pages | sort: "order" %}
    {% for page in mypages %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ page.url | absolute_url }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with it I found out what I needed to do. I made a folder under `_site` and called it `_data`, within that I made a file called `nav.yml` and added the following:

```
docs_list_title: someName
docs:

- title: Home
  url: index.html

- title: About
  url: about.html

- title: Blog
  url: /blog/index.html
```

Then in my layout I changed the `for loop` to the following:

```
{% for item in site.data.nav.docs %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ item.url | absolute_url }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```